# Send a key to another Windows application with C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm sort of new to c++. I'm trying to send a key to another application, which I know the HWND of. I was thinking of doing ::SendMessage but I'm not sure what parameters to use. I'm trying to send the space key. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310.aspx) might be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You want to send the WM_CHAR message with the space key character code as the wParam parameter:

```
SendMessage(
    hWnd,
    WM_CHAR,
    ' ', // space
    0);
```